# how to kill hung thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been trying to kill thread which are hung due to heavy IO operation.
I could have tried `thread.destroy` or `thread.stop` but they have been deprecated
For example have a look at below code

```
public class ThreadCheck {
private static int cnt = 0;
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running tasks");
          while (condition)                             {
                // **** Some IO operation that take forever ****                
                System.out.println("iteration " + cnt++);
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Breaking loop");
                    return;
                }   
            }           
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    t1.interrupt();
    System.out.println("thread destroyed..");

  }
}
```

Problem is i have added `interrupt` call but it never finishes IO call, so can i kill thread in such case

Comment: It depends on the exact IO operations. If you can change your code to use `InterrptibleChannel`, for example, you'll be able to achieve what you need. Anyway, the IO operation is essential for this to be answerable.

Comment: Yep, what he ^^^^ said!

Comment: @RealSkeptic i am reading some CSV files and inserting data from them into database, but sometimes these CSV files get corrupted and IO call never finishes, in this case does java have any implementation by which i can kill thread like in unix kill command

Comment: Or use `ExecutorService` and create timeouts for your method.

Comment: @Nomad: Yes, the Thread class has a `stop()` method that you'll find in the [Thread API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). But you'll also see in the API that you should **never** use this method and why. Again the solutions are as outlined above.

Comment: Thread.stop deprecated..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the actual code you are using, down to the basic Java classes and calls it uses (or well-known library classes and calls).

Comment: Exactly -- deprecated -- **never** call it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i am really sorry code is very lengthy so i tried to simply it here to ask question. I ma calling shell script using JSCH and those script reads csv files and insert data. The only workaround i have it here is to kill those processes at OS level manually

Comment: To make it simple, like unix have kill command, windows have task manager, what JAVA has to kill such threads?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this technique mentioned in this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html):

> **How do I stop a thread that waits for long periods (e.g., for input)?**
>
> That's what the Thread.interrupt method is for. The same "state based"
>   signaling mechanism shown above can be used, but the state change
>   (blinker = null, in the previous example) can be followed by a call to
>   Thread.interrupt, to interrupt the wait:

```
public void stop() {
    Thread moribund = waiter;
    waiter = null;
    moribund.interrupt();
}
```

> For this technique to work, it's critical that any method that catches
>   an interrupt exception and is not prepared to deal with it immediately
>   reasserts the exception. We say reasserts rather than rethrows,
>   because it is not always possible to rethrow the exception. If the
>   method that catches the InterruptedException is not declared to throw
>   this (checked) exception, then it should "reinterrupt itself" with the
>   following incantation:

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

> This ensures that the Thread will reraise the InterruptedException as
>   soon as it is able.
>
> **What if a thread doesn't respond to Thread.interrupt?**
>
> In some cases, you can use application specific tricks. For example,
>   if a thread is waiting on a known socket, you can close the socket to
>   cause the thread to return immediately. Unfortunately, there really
>   isn't any technique that works in general. It should be noted that in
>   all situations where a waiting thread doesn't respond to
>   Thread.interrupt, it wouldn't respond to Thread.stop either. Such
>   cases include deliberate denial-of-service attacks, and I/O operations
>   for which thread.stop and thread.interrupt do not work properly.